# Cleanly shutdown JGit

Tags: java, jgit, filehandle

I've created a local repository using JGit API's. When all processing is done, I'd like to delete the local repo (which is a simple java.io.File). However File.delete() operation fails. I'm already calling

```
org.eclipse.jgit.api.Git.close()
org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Repository.close()
```

Is there any further cleanup required?

Comment: I would use http://file-leak-detector.kohsuke.org/ to find out where there are still files open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing that I ran into was that if you use Git.cloneRepository().call(), you need to close the result that is returned, i.e.

```
    Git result = Git.cloneRepository()
            ....
            .call();

    try {
        ...
    } finally {
        result.close();
    }
```

See also [this code snippet](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/CloneRemoteRepository.java) from the [jgit-cookbook](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook)

Additionally some places in JGit that might keep file-handles open were fixed at some point after JGit 3.5.1, see [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=448570), so it might also help to ensure that you use the latest version of JGit if you are still using an older one.

Comment: Thank you so much! Closing the Git handle returned by cloneRepository() fixed the issue. I was using 3.6.1, so the JGit version wasn't an issue